# Find duplicates based on two fields and delete them

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `tourn_results` there are multiple records that share the same `tournamentId`.

Example of a `tourn_result` record set

```
uniqueId tournamentId playerRank
1        111          1
2        111          2
3        111          3

4        222          1
5        222          2
6        222          3

7        333          1
8        333          2
9        333          3
10       333          4

11       111          1
12       111          2
13       111          3
```

For each tournament there cannot be more than 1 `playerRank` = 1
(Only one first place per tournamentId)

I need to to find each duplicate and delete them, can't find a suitable answer. I appreciate your help.

Comment: The row with which uniqueid do you want deleted? For example you are saying a dup is [1, 111, 1] and [11, 111, 1]. Do you want the row with uniqueid 1 or 11 to stay?

Comment: It would help if you show us sample input _with_ duplicates and output minus the duplicates so we can see exactly what you have in mind.

Comment: @BrianDeMilia
The information in both 1 and 11 will be the same, so it doesn't matter which one is deleted.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen
The sample above does show the duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will delete everything but the rows with the lowest `uniqueid` for each combination of (`tournamentId`,`playerRank`).

```
delete from tourn_results x
where uniqueid <> ( select min(y.uniqueid)
                      from tourn_results y
                     where y.tournamentid = x.tournamentid
                       and y.playerrank = x.playerrank  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a unique index on the columns you don't want to have duplicates. It will drop all your duplicates.

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE tourn_result ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name (tournamentId, playerRank);
```

The other option is to create a new temp table, insert your duplicates rows and delete them from your actual table.

Comment: Wouldn't that truncate all results with the same tournamentId and the same rank?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, this is most easily done with a `left join`:

```
delete tr
    from tourn_results tr left join
         (select tr2.tournamentid, min(uniqueid) as minui
          from tourn_results tr2
          where tr2.playerrank = 1
          group by tr2.tournamentid
         ) ttr
         on ttr.minui = tr.minui and ttr.tournamentid = tr.tournamentid
    where tr.playerrank = 1 and ttr.minui is null;
```

I'm not so sure that deleting the additional "ties" for first place is the right thing to do, however.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be the right thing to do? If I want to see how many times a certain player achieved First Place, I wouldn't want to count duplicates.

Comment: What if two people are tied for first place?

Comment: That's very rarely the case. Maybe 1%. In the case of that there is a tie, I guess I could check for a different `playerName` or `playerId` on the selected field, however I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: @aRrOwDreWLs . . . I would suggest that you ask another question with sample data and desired results.  Handling ties is probably a bit more complicated.

Comment: I tried the code you put together with a `SELECT` in place of `DELETE` and it stopped short of gathering all duplicates, any idea why? It actually showed only "ties" which are erroneous as there aren't supposed to be any ties.